# Using Crossmint's payment elements with Unlock

Tags: ethereum, crossmint, unlock-protocol

I am using [Unlock](https://unlock-protocol.com/) to deploy some membership contracts and I want to enable card payments through [Crossmint](https://www.crossmint.com/). For this, I am using their `CrossmintPaymentElement` UI elements as they integrate nicely in Unlock's checkout modal.

I am using a pretty common Crossmint config and, the Elements are displayed as expected. However, when the user presses the `purchase` button, and Unlock's UI changes to its "payment processing" state, nothing seems to happen.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Can you share an outline of the config you're using and be sure to include the events you're listening for? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I have found the issue! The `payment:process.started` event triggered by the crossmint element is in fact triggered immediately, from the front-end, not from the backend... and since we used that event to show the loading state, then we actually "hid" the card form elements, which means that the Crossmint library is not able to access it when it needs to!

Comment: Stoked you figured it out! For anyone else be sure you wait for the `payment:preparation.succeeded` event before unmounting the `CrossmintPaymentElement` instead of the `payment:preparation.started` event.